# Writing text below the equations and side by side

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am currently writing some proofs of the theorem. I need to write the text as given below:

[image]

Comment: what you try so far? you should already know (regarding to your reputation) that you should provide mwe which demonstrate your problem.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36153/annotating-individual-math-terms-with-braces/36154

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
(a,b,c^2) = (a,\underbrace{b,c^2)(a,b}_{\text{some text}},c^2)
\]
\begin{align*}
(a,b,c^2) &\in (a,b,c^2) & \quad & (\text{by distribution law})\\
(a,b,c^2) &= a^2 b       & \quad & (\text{by .. law})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _write inside [....]_, please elaborate.